# No points on answering own bounty question

Tags: discussion, bounty

So I guess there are no bounty points to self if you answer your own bounty question?

[getResultImageLayer is not working](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/39275/getresultimagelayer-is-not-working)

Comment: The SE [FAQ](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work) says no.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you have seen is the expected behavior. You do not get the bounty points if you answer the question yourself.

See this discussion on meta.stackexchange: [Lost reputation after answering my own question with bounty](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18841/lost-reputation-after-answering-my-own-question-with-bounty)

Comment: This answer explains why : http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/18932